# Why does this regexp return infinite?

Tags: regex

Regular expression `[13579]?[13579]?` returns `infinite` (as http://regexr.com/ says).

Why? I just want to find two jointed odd numbers (**two**, not more) 😒.

Comment: The `?` means 0 or 1.  So, there's an infinite number of *nothings*.  Try removing both `?` characters.

Comment: in other words, your query would also work the same as `//`, which matches EVERYTHING, since there's nothing in the pattern.

Comment: Oh, I'm very distrate today. Of course, it should be `+`

Comment: The `+` would mean 1 or more odd numbers, which you have stated you don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `?` character in RegEx means zero or one of the preceding set.  So, your regular expression would match literally everything, as well as two odd numbers in a row.

You'll probably want something like:

```
[13579]{2}
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/G1DTmynXEYLUpSwg)

Which means *two and only two* of the preceding set.